# d3: Color Range with an array with more than 2 colors

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mapbox

I'm trying to shade a layer in a map (using `MapBox`) depending on the value of the properties in a .json file. However the code only works with 2 color values passed through. A snippet of my color coding is below.

```
  var color =
    d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(range)
    .range([#F0F0D0', '#228B22]);
```

It would fail if I do this

```
  var color =
    d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(range)
    .range(['930F16', '#F0F0D0', '#228B22]);
```

The map will display the range of the first two colors.

How would I extend if I wanted to do a range of colors beyond two? For instance, if I wanted the lower end to be `red`, the middle quantiles to be `white`, and the top quantiles to be `green`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([-1, 0, 1])
    .range(['#930F16', '#F0F0D0', '#228B22']);
```

This will interpolate between '#F0F0D0' and '#930F16' for negative values, and '#F0F0D0' and '#228B22' for positive values.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

The number of elements in the `range()` input array is truncated to match the number of elements in the `domain()`. To use three colors, you'll need to set the scale's `domain()` to have three elements as well. That's what you're (confusingly) calling `range` (the variable) in the snippet.

```
var color =
    d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([d3.min(data), (d3.max(data)-d3.min(data))/2, d3.max(data)])
        .range(['#930F16', '#F0F0D0', '#228B22']);
```